# Sending django queryset with annotate to my rest api

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have two simple models with random data about phones.

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='phone_img/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )
    slug_phone = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) 
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am able to send simple data via data the REST_framwork to my API.

**views.py**

```
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'market', )


    phone = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

Now i wanted to use the **annotate()** method with the **Min()** function in a QuerySet. I wanted to display the minimum price of each phone. So i tried something like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Min

<....>

class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        min_price = Phone.objects.annotate(Min('price__price'))

        return min_price
```

of course this did not work. i followed along the server errors messages and ended with this:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from market.models import Price, Phone


class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'market')

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('name', 'phone', 'market', )


    phone = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

My **API** shows me now this output, it´s not the min_price value, but at least something:

> {"count":7,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"name":"SAMSUNG
>   Galaxy S10"},{"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S10 plus"},{"name":"SAMSUNG
>   Galaxy S10e"},{"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S8"},{"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S8
>   Plus"},{"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S9"},{"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S9
>   plus"}]}

So i asked myself where to put **.annotate(Min** ? Or should i created a single **ListCreateAPIView** with queryset = Phone.objects.all() ? Is it possible to display the data of **min_price** without a new field in my serializers.py?

Comment: can you add the error traceback>?

Comment: If you try to find the min value from `Price` model, it won't return an expected result. Because, each row has only one `price` attribute, hence the `Min(price)` become `price` itself.

Comment: 1. With the serializers.py above, no error showed up. Only when i delete the lines wich includes class meta: model = Phone. Then the Error tells me that there is no Phone and price field. 2. ok i understand. That is why thought to go in my view / get_queryset with the "Phone.objects". Because then you have a certain Phone model "Samsung S10" for example and different prices. I guess i try to write a "ListCreateAPIView" only for Phone Model.

Comment: Yeah... But you should use the Phone Model with the serializer which you are intended to serialize them (phone querysets with Phone serializer). Also, should use the Phone Api along with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already mentioned some points in comments. But, I'm going to repeat that here :(
1. If you try to find the min value from Price model, it won't return an expected result. Because, each row has only one `price` attribute, hence the `Min(price)` become `price` itself.
2. If you want to serialize a queryset of a particular model (say **`Price`**), you should have used the ***`ModelSerializer`*** defined with `model=Price` in metaclass of the serializer.
3. You can't use two **`Meta`** classes in one serializer.
4. If you wish to display the **`Min(price)`** to the api, it is most suited to the **`Phone API`**

---

So,

#### 1. Remove the **`Phone`** meta class from **`PriceSerializer`**

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'market')

    phone = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

I'm not sure you are aware of the `StringRelatedField()` mechanism since you didn't do anything to your **`__str__()`** method of the **`Price`** model.

#### 2. Create a new serializer class for serializing the **`Price`** queryset

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    min_price = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = '__all__'
```

It's important to add a new field **`min_price`** to catch the annotated **`Min()`** value from the queryset.

### 3. Create a new view class to display the `Phone` list

```
class PhoneAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Phone.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price__price'))
    serializer_class = PhoneSerializer
```

The **`queryset`** attribute must be the ***annotated*** queryset.

### 4. wire up the view in `urls.py`